# Are URLSession objects resource intensive?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, urlsession

Would it be resource intensive to create a new URLSession for every single web request?

**Some background:**

I'm working on a library for making web requests. I'm trying to add a feature that allows downloading the result to a file that would also report its progress. For that, I'm going to have to become the session's delegate.

This wouldn't be a big deal except the public interface allows customizing the URLSession used for the requests. I don't want to override any customization the developer wants to do with its own delegate.

Right now, I'm thinking that the way to do this would be to secretly make a copy of the session they think is being used (yes I'm going to do more than copy the object itself) and then my internal delegate would call out to the original public session's methods. There could still be confusion/problems if they try to manipulate the session during the request, but that seems like a much smaller edge case.

My only concern right now is this might be very resource intensive if many requests are being made. Does anyone have a sense for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are intensive. Here is a quote from [Apple Staff on the developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84663).

> This is a common anti-pattern, one that we specifically
>   warned against at at WWDC this year.  Creating a session per request
>   is inefficient both on the CPU and, more importantly, on the network. 
>   Specifically, it prevents connection reuse, which can radically slow
>   down back-to-back requests.  This is especially bad for HTTP/2. We
>   encourage folks to group all similar tasks in a single session, using
>   multiple sessions only if you have different sets of tasks with
>   different requirements (like interactive tasks versus background
>   download tasks).  That means that many simple apps can get away with
>   using a single statically-allocated session.